# PyTorch equivalent of Numpy Round?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

`numpy.round()` optionally accepts a specified number of digits to round to. However, `torch.round` does not, and while [it seems like PyTorch will conform to NumPy eventually](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/65908), what are people's current solutions?

I just want a function like `torch.round(3.22, decimals=1)` that returns `3.2`.

Comment: I think torch doesnt round to decimals, so you could do something like propsed in the answers [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/round-tensor-to-x-decimal-places/25832)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own rounding function by

```
def round(x, decimals=0):
    b = 10**decimals
    return torch.round(x*b)/b
```